# Error por referência ambígua no Asp Net Core após instalação do pacote Google.Cloud.Firestore

Tags: asp.net-core

Olá,

Após a instalação do pacote `Google.Cloud.Firestore versão 2.3.1`, estou tendo erro de ambiguidade entre o `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` e `System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.ToListAsync` e por esse motivo não consigo fazer a consulta no banco de dados usando `await _dbContextMySQL.JogoOnLine.ToListAsync();`.

Já pesquisei e só encontrei esse comentário [aqui](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/5216), mas não resolveu.
Podem ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Após horas buscando uma solução, consegui contornar o conflito colocando `using static System.Linq.Enumerable` e `using static System.Linq.Queryable` em substituição ao `using System.Linq`. Não acho que isso seja uma solução ideal, mas segue a dica.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;
using static System.Linq.Queryable;
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;
```